# A single "Recommend Deletion" action in the Late Answers queue completes the review and nothing else ever happens

Tags: bug, status-review, review-queues, late-answers

I've been reviewing the late answers queue quite a bit recently, and I've slowly begun to realize that the "Recommend Deletion" action doesn't do what I thought it did. My impression, based on the name and my observation that this action completes the review, was that this would add the answer to the low quality answers queue for further review. However, I started to notice that answers I recommended to be deleted seemingly weren't getting any attention after 2+ weeks. I went back and flagged a couple of them to see what would happen, and within a couple days they were deleted.

The [help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-late-answers) also doesn't give any insight as to what this action does, but rather when to use it. <s>I do feel like this page *should* explain what each action does along with a couple examples of when and when not to use it, then let the user decide how to use it on a case-by-case basis, but that's for another discussion.</s> This caused me to start looking for some answers as to what it actually does. I found [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/145292/601145) which explains pretty clearly what it does, but it still doesn't make much sense to me *why* this is what it does.

> Yes, a sufficient number of delete recommendations (currently 6 on most sites, 4 on Stack Overflow) will cause the post to be deleted immediately, provided it has zero or negative score. (If it has a positive score, it will raise an automatic moderator flag instead.)

Thus, we come to my questions. Since (based on the description above) this action is supposed to allow multiple reviewers to vote (similar to close votes as I understand it), why doesn't this queue allow multiple people to vote on what should happen with the answer? Or at least do something to bring it to the attention of people that actually *can* delete or vote to delete it?

More importantly, *should* it be doing something like this (such as adding the answer to the low quality answers queue)? And, as a reviewer, what should I do about these answers? They are, after all, late answers, so if a review doesn't flag them and the OP doesn't flag them, then who will? Should I be flagging them as well as recommending their deletion?

Comment: As a specific example, [on this review in Late Answers, you recommended deletion](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/32727169). And... that was the end of the line. Your decision "completed" the review, and the answer didn't go anywhere else or have anything else happen to it. While I'm not sure that "recommend deletion" was the correct choice in that specific case, I agree that this is problematic in a *general sense*... if something needs to be deleted, and a user indicates that in review, but that's the end of the line and it never gets deleted, then that's not productive.

Comment: It shouldn't really mean that the answer is added to another review queue. Posts ping-ponging back and forth from one queue to another is one of the biggest flaws of the whole reviewing system. The real problem is that recommending deletion, while insufficient to actually do anything (which is reasonable; a single recommendation from an untrusted user shouldn't immediately result in deletion), marks the review as completed, thus preventing any other eyes from being placed on it. What it should do is either *not* complete the review (thus letting more people recommend deletion) or raise a flag.

Comment: To address the confusion in (now-deleted) comments: The problem, simply put, is that a single "recommend deletion" vote by a single reviewer marks the review as completed, and the system thus becomes completely satisfied, such that nothing ever happens. That makes a "recommend deletion" vote *de facto* equivalent to a "Looks OK" vote. I am not sure that Jesse's proposed solution of sending it to another review queue is necessarily the right solution, but this seems like a clear enough problem statement that highlights an actual flaw with the review queues.

Comment: @CodyGray Yes that's exactly what I'm trying to convey. It's not necessarily the fact that it's not getting deleted, it's the fact that it's not getting any further attention after I recommend it to be deleted. I would be perfectly fine with people disagreeing with me and saying it looks okay, but that doesn't even happen.

Comment: As it turns out, [this same bug/flaw has been noted by a moderator of another site and brought up for discussion on the global Meta site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/371918). Unfortunately, it hasn't yet been resolved. I flagged it to have a moderator add the [status-review] tag.

Answer (score 20):

As Cody noted, [I noticed this last November](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/371924) after it was brought up on MSE, but that answer never gained apparent traction with staff, and I never got around to bringing it up again in a new post specifically about the queue being broken, as you now have.

Need to clarify, though– this bug affects plain ol' "Delete" actions from trusted users in the queue as well (presumably those get a vote actually logged to the post, however?):

[image: LA review completed with a single "Delete" action]

As for how the queue *should* work, in the [Review Queue project conclusion post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369013), it was specified that the new "Recommend deletion" and "Delete" actions would work the same way: the review would continue, and 6 accumulated review actions of either type would delete the post:

[image: Late Answers queue flowchart, indicating that posts in review would be left in the queue if they accumulated delete review actions]

But clearly, as you've noted, this isn't actually occurring. In fact, this broken behavior has been occurring non-stop since that very same announcement, according to SEDE.

If we pull all (non-skip) review actions for completed reviews in the Late Answers queue, where the review was completed with either a "Recommend deletion" or "Delete" action, then we can see that [nearly *18,000 reviews* have ended prematurely since the change was rolled out](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1614001/broken-late-answers-reviews):

[image: Data table showing that all reviews ending with either type of "Delete" review action have ended after only 1 or 2 actions, and that this started occurring in late August of 2021, the same time as the review queue project concluded]
<sup>[Link to query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1614001/broken-late-answers-reviews); chart sorted by review action count (desc.), then by review creation date (desc.)</sup>

This data implies that the two delete actions from LA review appear to have *never served their purpose even a single time since release*, given this bug, which is very disheartening. That's a lot of reviewer time thrown to the wind over the last year.